# Python - Pandas - openpyxl: Problems loading workbook

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

For some reason, I am not able to load an Excel file via Pandas or openpyxl in my script. The error I get is:
ImportError: cannot import name 'load_workbook'

The strange thing is when I compile using Hydrogen in Atom (using Jupyter kernel) it executes. When I run it in Atom w/ Script, I get the above error.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you show how you are importing it? Should be `from openpyxl import load_workbook` or you can `import openpyxl` then use `openpyxl.load_workbook`

Comment: @CoryKramer, I hadn't tried just importing all of openpyxl. I just did and get the same error. For completeness, I have tried calling from Pandas (import Pandas as pd, then use pd.ExcelFile(file_name)) and openpyxl (from openpyxl import Workbook  -  i also tried from openpyxl import load_workbook). All yield the same result.

Comment: @CoryKramer, I have also gone so far as to uninstall my anaconda implementation and make a new one using choco. I have also tried making a virtual environment with all the requisites and all yield same result. I have ALSO explicitly setting PATH variables pointing directly to the openpyxl site-packages in hopes that by some strange way it was tied to that... I'm stuck.